# Macro copy to above cell?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to make a simple macro to paste what I select to the cell above it, however for some reason it would always default to a fixed cell so I've tried to use offset to move it from its starting position. However it doesn't work and I just get an "Argument not optional" error.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
'
    Selection.Copy
    Range.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Is it that I have to turn my selection into a range and if so how do I do that?

Comment: second line is wrong. `Range`...which range ? (downvote not me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your macro would work if you chage the Range line:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```